# 'select top' returns too many rows

Tags: t-sql

```
insert into
    @resultSet
SELECT TOP (@topN)  
    field1,
    field2
FROM    
    dbo.table1 DataLog  
WHERE           
    DataLog.SelectedForProcessing is null
```

I'm passing `300` into `@topN` in the above sql, a value I've got configured in my app.config file, but this query running on 2 different servers has returned 304 rows in one instance and 307 rows in another instance.

I cant find anywhere that may be interfering with the 300, to turn it into 304 or 307, so I'm beginning to wonder whether SQL Server will just return a few extra rows sometimes? (Same code on another server IS returning the expected 300 rows)

Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: Sql wont return extra rows, use profiler to check what value the sql is getting for @topN

Comment: it's running at an awkward time in the morning, test runs work as expected, same code on other servers work as expected. confused.com

Answer (score 2):

Test this

```
declare @topN int = 100;
select @topN ;
delete * from @resultSet;
insert into
    @resultSet
SELECT TOP (@topN)  
    field1,
    field2
FROM    
    dbo.table1 DataLog  
WHERE           
    DataLog.SelectedForProcessing is null;
select count(*) 
FROM    
dbo.table1 DataLog  
WHERE           
    DataLog.SelectedForProcessing is null;
select count(*) from @resultSet;
```

Comment: Thanks for adopting my `DELETE` suggestion, and for the clever comment. Upvoted :-)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server will consistently return `TOP N` rows when `N` is a constant value - no wiggle room there.

I see two possibilities:

1. `@topN` is getting a different value on occasion
2. `@resultSet` is somehow not empty before having new values inserted

If `@resultSet` is a variable declared elsewhere in your scripts, check to see that no other `INSERT INTO` statements might be leaving unnecessary rows.

One easy way to implement this in run-time would be to simply add another command before this `INSERT INTO` statement:

```
DELETE @resultSet;
INSERT INTO
    @resultSet
SELECT TOP (@topN)  
    field1,
    field2
FROM    
    dbo.table1 DataLog  
WHERE           
    DataLog.SelectedForProcessing IS NULL
;
```

Comment: @3BK the `@resultSet` variable is declared in each call of the stored procedure, so definitely no pre-filled data in there

Comment: And you're absolutely positive that `@topN` is 300? If so, I guess I can't help you... As stated here in the comments, *fewer* rows would be an option (if there weren't enough); but *excess* rows is another story.  Is the query posted in your question exact? Are you using any other keywords, like `WITH TIES`, in your `SELECT` statement?

Comment: @3BK. `select` has an additional where clause, that's about it, removed for simplicity. As the same config on different servers is returning different rows, it really has me baffled, thought the internet may have heard of this happening before. I've double checked the code, value is straight from the config file, unless converting a string in app.config on some days just adds a few. i.e. `"300" == 304` on some days, and `== 300` on other days? cause that is what is happening. and then some servers are `300`'ing each day perfectly. just plain odd.

Comment: @3BK, figured it out. I'm `select`ing `topN`, then using those rows to update a `SelectedForProcessing` col, but some records have duplicate keys, so the 300 rows are updating 304, not a `top` problem at all. shouldn't have duplicates, but thats an entirely other problem.

Comment: @Nnoel I'm glad that you figured it out, and I have to say that I'm not surprised that eventually it turned out to be elsewhere; as stated, `TOP` has very predictable behavior, by and large.  Hopefully we've been helpful anyway :) Have a good one!